# How do I re-shape an array with shape(band,row,column) to (row,column,band)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array with shape(370,275,210) and I want to re-shape it to (275,210,370). How would I achieve this in Python? 370 is the number of bands,275 is the number of rows, and 210 is the number of columns contained in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I suppose that you need to swap the axis 0 with 2.

```
np.swapaxes(x, 0, 2)
```

That is probably an hyperspectral image?

Comment: okay, i have also been working on hyperspectral images.I can suggest you that  (http://www.spectralpython.net/ )   python module

Comment: @Ibrahim- I am using the same one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [np.moveaxis()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html)

```
>>> a = np.zeros((370, 275, 210))
>>> a.shape
(370, 275, 210)
>>> a = np.moveaxis(a, 0, 2)
>>> a.shape
(275, 210, 370)
```